# How do I get my $_POST variables to post?

Tags: php, html, post

This is my first page, which would be my login page. The user types in their username, hits login, and then the broswer should take them to login.php Index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body >

<br><br><br><br><h2 align=center>Quiz Taker</h2>
<br><br><br>
<p align=center></p>

<br>
    <form method="post" action="login.php">
        <table class="login" cellpadding=10 cellspacing=0 align="center" bgcolor="#cccccc" border="3">
        <tr>
            <td>
            <input type="radio" name="userType" value="Student"/> Student
            <input type="radio" name="userType" value="Teacher"/> Teacher
             <td>
             Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="username" size=10>
             </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td colspan=2 align="center">
             <input type="submit" name="submit" value="  Log In  ">
             </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

When the user hits submit it will go to login.php which looks like this:

```
<?php

include_once("DatabaseConnection.php");

$stmt=$DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM QuizUser where Name=?")
$stmt->bindValue(1, $_POST['username']);
$stmt->execute();
if ($row=$stmt->fetch())
    {
        $ID=$row['ID'];
    }
    else
    {

        $stmt=$DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO QuizUser(Name) VALUES(?)")
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $_POST['username']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $ID=$DBH->lastInsertId();
    }
    $_SESSION['userID']= $ID;
    $_SESSION['userName']= $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION['userType']=$_POST['userType'];

    if($_POST['userType'] == "Student")
    {
        header($string["Location:student.php"]);
    }
    else 
    {
        header($string["Location:teacher.php"]);    
    }

    ?>
```

Which is not working and I cannot figure out why. It just pops up a parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in ....myfile.... at line whever the first time I try and use the $_POST variable. By the way, I am starting my session in the DataBaseConnection.php that is imported at the top of login.php.

Comment: You question isn't really related to your problem. There's something wrong with the syntax of your PHP script. You'll need to post the exact error message.

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after `$stmt=$DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM QuizUser where Name=?")`

Comment: Thanks, I added that but still didn't fix anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `header` functions are written incorrectly.

```
header($string["Location:student.php"]);
```

should be

```
header("Location: student.php");
```

Likewise,

```
header($string["Location:teacher.php"]);
```

should be

```
header("Location: teacher.php");
```

Comment: That fixed it. I am now being redirected. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a semi colon in

```
$stmt=$DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM QuizUser where Name=?")
```

and

```
$stmt=$DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO QuizUser(Name) VALUES(?)")
```

Comment: Awesome so that fixed the parse error. But now it is still not taking either of the header statements. It is my understanding those will redirect you to "Location:whever.php"

Comment: When I go to the provided link http://atr.eng.utah.edu/~kline/ps10/login.php, In the error message, it says "Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'Name' cannot be null'" > that means you have a column named "Name" in the table "QuizUser" and you have set that field as "not nullable". If it is not mandatory to have a "name" value in the table, set that field as nullable.

Comment: Name is null by default so it should except null

Comment: but you may have created "Name" field as a field with "unique" index. So after first insertion, it gives this error. Where do you create $string[] array in header($string["Location:student.php"]); ? Is it a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

here

```
include_once("DatabaseConnection.php");
```

you'd better use

```
require_once("DatabaseConnection.php");
```